# Click radio button automatically - greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, radio-button, greasemonkey

I have 3 radio buttons and need to choose one (BAT) when the page loads.  Here is the HTML in question.

```
<td valign="center">
     <input id="T1" name="ZZ" type="radio" value="CAT"/> <label for="T1"> cat </label><br/>
     <input id="T2" name="ZZ" type="radio" value="DOG"/> <label for="T2"> dog </label><br/>
     <input id="T3" name="ZZ" type="radio" value="BAT"/> <label for="T3"> bat </label><br/>
</td>
```

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].value == "BAT") {
        elements[i].click();
    }
}
```

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong? The radio button is never selected unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `checked` property:

```
elements[i].checked = true;
```

Comment: Hmmmm, that didn't seem to help it do anything.   I'll have to take another look at this problem.